# Flot: how to add "mousedown" event to a plot holder?

Tags: jquery, events, flot, onmousedown

I want to add `"mousedown"` event to the plot holder in JQuery/Flot code, i tried two ways, but neither works, i appreciate anybody give me any hints!

1）

```
placeholder.bind("mousedown",function(e){
    alert("1");
})
```

2)

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
    alert("1");
}

plot.hooks.bindEvents.push(function (plot, eventHolder) {
    eventHolder.mousedown(onMouseDown);
});
```

Comment: What is placeholder? How is it defined? [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qnff3/)

Comment: Hi Scoobler, good example for me as a newbie. i just added more detials to this question. hope you have some time to take a look, thanks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737347/extjs-jquery-flot-mousedown-event-for-the-plot-container

Answer (score 0):

Simon ,

If they are dynamically added elements after the DOM , try live . Normal bind doesn't work if they are added at run time.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: hi. thanks for this advice. however, it still doesnt work. placeholder.live("mousedown",function(e){
  alert("1");
 })

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you've mistaken what the call to `$.plot` returns.  It doesn't give you back a jQuery object, it gives you back a `Plot` object.

So most likely, if you have something like this as your HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
```

You want to do a bind like this:

```
$('#placeholder').mousedown(function(){
  alert('mouse down')
});
```

Comment: hi Ryley,thanks for your reply. i just added some details to this question, appreciate any comments while you have time to take a look. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737347/extjs-jquery-flot-mousedown-event-for-the-plot-container

Answer (score 0):

In flot , You can bind events using hooks . There is a hook called bindEvents which you can use to bind any event.

example:

```
     function myClick(plot, eventHolder){
       eventHolder.mouseover((e)=>console.log('You preses the mouse at',e.pageX+""+e.pageY))
     }

     let options = { hooks: {bindEvents: [myClick]}}
```

The Documentation is in good detail about this
https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md