# ExtJS + JQuery/Flot: mousedown event for the plot container

Tags: plot, mouseevent, flot, extjs, pan

I realized that in flot there is a confliction between "plotpan" event and "mousedown" event. if enable the plot pannable, then mousedown wont work in the plot area; also, if disable "plotpan" event, but enable "plotclick" event and "mousedown" event, it turns out that only mousedown works but plotclick doesnt. how can I make sure that these three or more events can work in a more apporpriate way? demo codes are attached as follows:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>A Test Page</title>
<!-- JQUERY/FLOT LIB FILES -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
    src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
    src="lib/jquery/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
    src="lib/jquery/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
    src="lib/jquery/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

        // raw data
        d1 = [ [ 0, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ];
        d2 = [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 4, 2 ] ];


        //event data
        dataSeries = [{
            color : "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
            data : d1,

            label : "point1",
            points : {
                show : true,
                symbol : "square",
                radius : 4
            }

        }, {
            color : "rgb(255, 100, 123)",
            data : d2,

            label : "point2",
            points : {
                show : true,
                radius : 4
            }
        }];

        //container for graph
        var placeholder = $("#flotDiv");

        if (placeholder.length <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        options= {//graph options

                pan : {
                    interactive : true
                },

                grid: {
                    clickable:true
                }
            };

        $.plot(placeholder, dataSeries, options);

        placeholder.bind("mousedown",function(e){
            alert("mousedown");
        })

        /*
        placeholder.bind("plotclick",function(event, pos, item){
            alert("plotclick");
        });
        */
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- SLD PLOT -->
    <div id="flotDiv" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the above codes, mousedown event doesnt work because i enable plot pannable; if i disable plotpan, then mousedown will work; and if I enable plotclick, still only mousedown works; i know that both plotpan and plotclick are relevant to "mousedown" event, so there is a confliction among. however, i need find a way to make them work together.

appreciate any comments!

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your Ext setup - that's probably the issue.  Give us more code, or put an example on the internet somewhere?

Comment: Hi Ryley, i changed my question again by adding a whole example. thanks for your attention~

Answer (score 1):

The plugin jquery.flot.navigate.js using for zooming and panning third party plugin jquery.event.drag.js which will cancel mousedown propagation. Solution could be to return **true** inside mousedown event hadler to allow bubbling out the mouse down event.